# Changing the background of an androidplots to white

Tags: android, androidplot

I have being playing around with the ListView of XYPlots. I was able to change background either by using style="@style/APDefacto.Light" or style="@style/APDefacto.Dark". These two work well but, I want my graph to have complete white background instead of a light or dark background.

Screenshot with the light background.

[image]

If you look carefully at the graph, you will see that the background has a grey color but the graph itself is white. I want the whole background to be completely white.

I have try the solution of the link [Change the background color of XYplot in android to white?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993725/change-the-background-color-of-xyplot-in-android-to-white). But that only have the effect of removing the square on the graph but no change is seen on the background.

Below is the resulting screenshot.

[image]

Any clues,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just add these attrs to your XYPlot's xml:

```
ap:backgroundColor="#FFF"
ap:graphBackgroundColor="#FFF"
```